# Error while importing csv in Python using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, python-import

I have started to learn Python for data science. I am already using R on almost daily basis. I stack on first step. I try to import csv file using Pandas read_csv file method. I have problem with encoding the file while importing.

If I use read.csv from R everything is ok:

```
df <- read.csv2("some_path/myfile.txt", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

but if I use similar code in python:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("some_path/myfile.txt", sep = ';', encoding= 'utf8')
```

it returns an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc6 in position 13: invalid continuation byte
```

How is it possible that I can import a file with "utf-8" encoding in R, but not in Python?

If I use different encoding (latin1 or iso-8859-1), it imports the file successfully but characters are not encoded in right way.

Comment: Ok, I suppose `cp1250` encoding works just fine.

Comment: Please show us a sample of your `myfile.txt` to help us to understand better the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even if I don't understand why UTF-8 works in R but not in Python, I found out that cp1250 encoding works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Use encoding "UTF-16". I used that to resolve my issue with the same error.

Comment: Do you mean that using `utf-16` solved your problem or do you mean it still gives you the same problem?